# ¿Como obtener una email y password encriptada en url de django?

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes queridos amigos de stackoverflow.

Deseo saber como puedo sacar una email y una password encriptada desde una url en django gracias.

url.py

```
path('validate_email/<slug:username>/(?P<slug:email>[\w-@]+)/<slug:password>', views.validate_email, name="validate_email"),
```

este es un ejemplo lo que deseo extraer y muchas gracias:

***http://127.0.0.1:8000/validate_email/username/email@email.com/$pbkdf2-sha256$12000$0jqnNMbYOydkrNU6x3jvPYewNsbYWwuhtPae8x4j5Lw$.TbrKDjnp3A/Ccp1BA1jn5/Pd9IG93DUUgWea8JASVU/***

Comment: No veo muy seguro que muestres una contraseña encriptada de ningún modo. Menos en una url. Sin embargo a partir de un usuario obtenerlo es fácil luego solo es cuestión de reemplazar en el string de la url, `request.user.email` el email no se encripta, y `request.user.password` que ya está encriptada por django

Comment: solo quisiera como poder construir la url ya sea que quiera tomar la password o no !

Comment: Mira [acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) y [acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) para más información de como hacer lo que pides